# instantiation fault in indomain

Tags: prolog, eclipse-clp

I have a board solver which its general form of the solver likes the below:

```
solver(Board):-
    constraints(Board),
    search(Board).
```

It passes the constraint predicate, but there is an error in the search part which comes in the below:

```
search(Board):-
    term_variables(Board,Vars),
    sd:labeling(Vars).
```

The error occurs in the labeling predicate , and the error is:

> instantiation fault in indomain(_258{[9 .. 13, 15 .. 20]})

So what is the problem? (I can't see inany problem in the indomain predicate).

Comment: You seem to be mixing features from library(ic) and library(sd). If your variable domain has been created with library(ic), then have to use the labeling predicate from library(ic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @jschimpf in the comment, the vital point here is **mixing features of two libraries might not be possible**. Hence, the safe code is promoted to use the same features of the same library as it is possible. The same thing happens here. `constraint(Board)` using the `#=` (as an integer suspension) from the `ic` library, but in the `labeling`, the code tries using the `sc` library. That is the origin of the problem.

You should notice that it could be one reason for this bug message.